# What was the main purpose of the Exodus?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, yetziat-mitzrayim, slave-serve-eved-avadim, kabbalat-hatorah, parshanut-theory

From some pesukim it seems that the main purpose of yetzias mitzrayim was to provide relief from their burdens and bring them to the promised land

e.g. Shemos 3:8

> וָאֵרֵד לְהַצִּילוֹ מִיַּד מִצְרַיִם וּלְהַעֲלֹתוֹ מִן הָאָרֶץ הַהִוא אֶל אֶרֶץ טוֹבָה וּרְחָבָה אֶל אֶרֶץ זָבַת חָלָב וּדְבָשׁ אֶל מְקוֹם הַכְּנַעֲנִי וְהַחִתִּי וְהָאֱמֹרִי וְהַפְּרִזִּי וְהַחִוִּי וְהַיְבוּסִי.
>
> I have come down to deliver them from the hand of Egypt and to bring them up from that land to a good and broad land, to a land flowing with milk and honey, to the place of the Canaanites, the Hittites, the Emorites, the Perizzites, the Hivvites and the Jebusites.

ibid 3:17

> וָאֹמַר אַעֲלֶה אֶתְכֶם מֵעֳנִי מִצְרַיִם אֶל אֶרֶץ הַכְּנַעֲנִי וְהַחִתִּי וְהָאֱמֹרִי וְהַפְּרִזִּי וְהַחִוִּי וְהַיְבוּסִי אֶל אֶרֶץ זָבַת חָלָב וּדְבָשׁ
>
> and I have said, 'I will take you up from the affliction of Egypt to the land of the Canaanites, the Hittites, the Emorites, the Perizzites, the Hivvites, and the Jebusites, to a land flowing with milk and honey.

while from others it seems that the end goal was HaShem dwelling among them and  becoming their God which presumably refers to accepting his Torah

e.g. ibid 29:46

> וְיָדְעוּ כִּי אֲנִי י"י אֱלֹהֵיהֶם אֲשֶׁר הוֹצֵאתִי אֹתָם מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם לְשׇׁכְנִי בְתוֹכָם אֲנִי י"י אֱלֹהֵיהֶם.
>
> And they shall know that I am Hashem, their God, who took them out from the land of Egypt to dwell among them. I am Hashem their God

Vayikrah 22:33

> הַמּוֹצִיא אֶתְכֶם מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם לִהְיוֹת לָכֶם לֵאלֹהִים אֲנִי י"י.
>
> who brought you out of the land of Egypt, to be your God. I am Hashem."

How to reconcile?

Comment: Why does it have to need to be reconciled? Maybe it's just all connected with each other?! To me it seems that we needed to get out of Mitzrayim, to let go of the impurity and head towards the holy path. Otherwise the Torah could've be given in Mitzrayim, but the point was to be freed from slavery and to make ourselves worthy receiving the Torah.

Comment: Interesting to note that the first commandment says "I am...who took you out of Egypt", like saying "I did you a favour, now it's your turn to do Me a favour"

Comment: Another facet in regard to the purpose of the first redemption that you don’t comment on is the fulfillment of G-d’s promises. That both aspects you note are details of the fulfillment of G-d’s covenant with Avraham, Yitzchok and Yisroel. שנאמן הוא. For those who learn Chabad Chassidut, consider the distinction between הוא and אתה. Also, reflect on the meaning of אמן.

Comment: I should also mention that the 4 cups which correspond to the 4 geulos stop short of a 5th cup apparently emphasizing the Torah (vlakachti) over the national homeland (vheiveisi)

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the above falls under one thing: He wanted to become our God. This is the phrase that is repeated all over, in many variations, including in the daily Shema prayer, that He took us out of Egypt in order to be our God.

This is a statement of relationship. Therefore everything else is connected: He is showing that He is ready to commit to us, by saving us from our burdens, He wants to dwell with us, in the Holy land.

Comment: Please see my comment above to the question posed. Shabbat shalom, my friend.